# mongodb change $group output format

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have the following document structure

```
{
  "timestamp" : 13512493603565120,<br>
  "value" : 1,<br>
  "y" : 42,<br>
  "M" : 513,<br>
  "w" : 2234,<br>
  "d" : 15639,<br>
  "S" : 46918,<br>
  "h" : 375347,<br>
  "m" : 22520822,<br>
  "s" : 1351249360,<br>
  "_id" : ObjectId("508aa61100b5457c04000001"),<br>
  "__v" : 0<br>
}
```

I have a mongodb aggregate as follows to sum up values grouping by field y:

`aggregate({ 
    $group : {_id : "$y", value:{$sum:4}}
})`

This will give me

`[
  {
    "_id": 42,
    "value": 16
  }
]`

What I want now is to format this output so that it looks like this:

`[
 [13512493603565100, 2],
 [13512493605167900, 1]
]`

ie:

`[
 [<timestamp>,<sum of value grouped by field y>],
 [<timestamp>,<sum of value grouped by field y>]
]`

I looked at $project but I still cant figure out how I can use it to get the desired output

Comment: In order to get your desired output, you would have to be grouping by `timestamp` -- it doesn't make sense to group by `y` and then add the `timestamp` field because there will be multiple values.  Perhaps you actually want your group `_id` to be on both `y` and `timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as of now apparently (using mapreduce or aggregate).
Hope this will be added soon.

Comment: Is it still the case today? Would appreciate to hear your feedback today